# pygame 1.9 doesn't seem to load png

Tags: image, sockets, python-2.7, pygame

I am toying around with pygame and WX for some self study projects I am doing to improve my skills. I am trying to send a png over a socket server in python 2.7.3 and load the png into pygame.
I have confirmed I can receive the png over the localhost but I cant load my png.

this the RDPC.py file that is giving trouble:

```
import os
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from threading import Thread
import time
import socket
import shutil
def recvFile():
    file = open("data2/screenshot.png","wb")
    while 1:
            data = s.recv(2048)
            if not data:
                    break
            file.write(data)
    file.close()
    shutil.copyfile('data2/screenshot.png', 'data2,screen.png')
    image = pygame.image.load('data2/screen.png')
    screen.blit(image,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

class RDPclient(object):
    def main(self, rdpserver):
        self.insert(rdpserver)
    def insert(self, rdpserver):
        done = False
        while not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    rdpserver.mouse(x,y)
                elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        self.mouseDragEvent(x,y)
                        self.mouseMoveEvent(x,y)
                if (event.type == KEYDOWN):
                    rdpserver.keyboard(event)
                    if (event.type == KEYUP):
                        rdpserver.keyboard(event)
                    if (event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                        done = True
    def mouseDownEvent(self,x,y):
        pass

    def mouseUpEvent(self,x,y):
        pass

    def mouseDragEvent(self,x,y):
        pass

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,x,y): 
        pass
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024,768), pygame.RESIZABLE)
white = (255, 255, 255)
screen.fill(white)
pygame.display.set_caption('PyRDP')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(1)
t_bytes = 1024*1024*1
HOST = '127.0.0.1' 
PORT = 9999
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
rec = Thread(target=recvFile)
rec.start()
```

Only the above code recvFile function is giving me trouble.

If you need the other parts of the code, post back and ill post them ASAP.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with you using the string `'data2,screen.png'` instead of `'data2/screen.png'` when you call `shutil.copyfile` but then try to load it as `'data2/screen.png'`?

Comment: Thats a typo while trying to put the code on stack overflow. I tried the suggestion below to put all the client files in the same place as where the screenshot gets recieved. the screen does go  white but the image is not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble with this too. 
You need to have all of the files (image code) in the same place like a folder or your desktop. Hope I helped!

Comment: `def recvFile():
        file = open("screenshot.png","wb")
        while 1:
                data = s.recv(2048)
                if not data:
                        break
                file.write(data)
        file.close()
        shutil.copyfile("screenshot.png", "screen.png")
        image = pygame.image.load('screen.png')
        screen.blit(image,(0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()` i changed the code to this and I s till diddnt recieve the png in pygame

Comment: im going to accepr your awnswer as looking as this did solve part of the issue.